# Push notification not working on producation

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification

I was able to receive push notifications on device using development SSL certificate. Now, I am trying to do it on the production app.

The server shows that the message was delivered successfully, but the device is not receving the message.

I can't understand what's wrong here. 
How can I check what what is breaking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the solution. I created the .app using the **release mode** & my problem got resolved. Earlier I have created the build using debug mode.